# Javascript - How do I access groups of items from Firebase at a time?

Tags: javascript, firebase

When my page loads, I'd like to load up 20 items out of my Firebase database. However, when I scroll down a certain point (think endless scroll), I want to display the NEXT 20 items in Firebase.

Looking through the documentation, I don't really see an obvious way to go through the first 20 objects and then later the next 20 objects.

I was thinking of this to load three items but it won't do the next three items:

```
ref.limitToLast(numItemsPerLoad).on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    writeToPage(snapshot, ul);
});
```

Any ideas? The new Firebase documentation isn't as straightforward as the old one

**EDIT**

So I'm trying to initialize my startAtKey to the first link's "key" child of my database. But my print statements are all out of whack. Is there something I'm missing about where Javascript returns from or something?

Here's the code:

```
var ref;
var startAtKey;
function extractImage(){
    var database = firebase.database();

    var featuredRef = database.ref("Featured/");
    var projectsRef = database.ref("Projects/");
    var featured_ul = document.getElementById("featured_links");
    var normal_ul = document.getElementById("normal_links");

    //Read featured section first
    readSection(featuredRef, featured_ul);

    startAtKey = initializeStartAtKey(projectsRef);
    console.log("startAtKey is " + startAtKey); //This doesn't print '1' like it should

    //Randomly read the rest of the sections
    readSection(projectsRef, normal_ul);
}

function initializeStartAtKey(ref){
    console.log("INSIDE INTIALIZE");
    ref.orderByChild("key").limitToFirst(1).once("child_added", function(snapshot){
        console.log("key is " + snapshot.val().key);
        return snapshot.val().key;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do range queries with the `.startAt()` and `.endAt()` methods.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('items');

function getNextItems(ref, startAtKey, numberOfItems) {
   var query = ref.startAt(startAtKey).limitToFirst(numberOfItems);
   return query;
}

function getPreviousItems(ref, endAtKey, numberOfItems) {
   var query = ref.endAt(endAtKey).limitToFirst(numberOfItems);
   return query;   
}
```

The catch is you need to know the key to start at, and this is dependent on how you're setting up your application code. Find a way for you to figure out what the last item on the page is before you need to load more, and use that item's key at the `startAtKey`.

[**See the docs here for more info.**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#data-order)

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to keep track of the startAtKey, but I can't even simply initialize it to the first value of the first item (see edit)